# Ractive js 0.10 index from context

Tags: ractivejs

I'm upgrading an app from 0.7 and in an event I had access to the current stack of indexes:

event.index.myIndex

now instead of event I have context, is there an analogue of this or do I need to explicitly pass @index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is get the index from context with `ctx.get('@index')`